# Transitive Action of a Finite Group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

If $G$ is a finite group acts transitively on a set $\mathbb{X}$. Does this imply that the set $\mathbb{X}$ is finite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ acts transitively on $X$, then, given $x\in X$, for every $y\in X$ there is some $g\in G$ such that $y=g\cdot x$. This is precisely the condition for a *surjection* $f_x\colon G\longrightarrow X$ to exist. Therefore the cardinality of $G$ is *at least* equal to the one of $X$.

(Incidentally, since by group action's axioms distinct $x$'s induce distinct $f_x$'s, there are $|X|$ of such surjections.)

Comment: So the set $X$ must be finite.

Comment: @Neilhawking, Yes, correct

Comment: Of cause. You get $\# X \leq \# G < \infty$.